# Java - Functional interface for merging two lists

Tags: java, lambda

Hello dear colleagues.

As an exercise for Java streams, I've written simple program, which scrapes links to references from a news portal. Basically, I wanted to find out, which portals are the most referenced.

Right now, I ended up with the following piece of code:

```
final Map<String, List<URL>> hostToURLs = Analyzer.mapByHost(ReferencesStore.read());
// E.g. bbc.com -> [ https://www.bbc.com/article1, https://www.bbc.com/article2, etc ]

// The following creates LinkedHashMap sorted by the number of URLs        
final LinkedHashMap<String, List<URL>> sortedHostToURLs = hostToURLs
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (m, n) -> { m.addAll(n); return m; }, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

I'm interested, if the the ugly merge lambda
`(m,n)-> {m.addAll(n); return m;}`
in the collect method can be replaced with some method reference from  standard library. I wasn't able to find anything useful in the  documentation, nor was I able to ask google the right question to find out if such merge function exists. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why convert back to a map? Just print each `Map.Entry`

Comment: I'm using the sorted Map in following method calls, where I want the data to be sorted. Thank you for pointing this out. The print statement was there only for initial debugging purposes. I removed it so hopefully my intention with the code is more clear now.

Comment: "How do I join to lists in Java?" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java) suggests that Java does not provide a List concatenation method; the alternatives all suggest converting the lists to streams, concatenating the streams, and converting the output stream to a list.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that the merge function is never called in your case, because all you are doing is reordering an existing map, so IMO you don't really need to worry about it.

Personally in such cases I just use `(m, n) -> m`, because it's short and doesn't distract.

Another variant would be to use a function that throws an exception when called. The JDK [does this itself](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l132) when you use the `toMap` overload that doesn't take a merge function:

```
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
  return (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); };
}
```

Another thing you may want to consider it not to use a `(Linked)HashMap` at all here, but simply collect the `Entry`s into a list. If you need to lookup an entry by key later, then just keep the original map around.

---

EDIT: In cases where the merge function is used, your implemention is fine. You may want to just put it in a variable, so that its name can describe its function.

One thing you could consider is using a function that creates a new list instead of "reusing" one of the existing lists. That would reflect the functional style of the code better, where one normally uses immutable data structures.

The basic problem is that Java's `List` interface isn't intended for functional/immutable situations and doesn't have a simple method to concatinate two lists.

If you are open to additional libraries you'd have more options. For example, Apache's Commons has a [`union` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#union-java.util.List-java.util.List-).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I din't realised the merge function is not called. But still, for the sake of my curiosity, would be there a better solution than the mine if the scenario was a bit different and the merge function was called?

Comment: @AnotherNoob See edit.